# Identify which user added ppas

Tags: apt, ppa

I am responsible for a system, which someone else had setup. Sadly we just started documentation after I took the honor. We had an issue with old bionic packages since we dist-upgraded to 20.04 and solved it, but we are still messing with a few ppa's which I in first place need to figure out what they provide and in second place who installed them.

Is it possible to figure this out?

Comment: The Launchpad page for each PPA contains a 'description' field. Alternately, you can use `apt redepends <package_name>` and `apt-cache policy <package_name>` to untangle the dependencies...if you have a package name to start the process. Or you can list the PPAs in your question.

Comment: 1. Yes, list the PPAs. Someone here should be able to identify it; 2. It may be difficult to know who added them into your computer system, but it needs elevated permissions, so it must be someone who had 'sudo' access.

Comment: 1. Identifiying which is not the problem for me. 2. part is my trouble and yes I now they are sudoers, but there was alot going on in the past with the system and I wanted to know which of them installed the ppa. Two of the sudoers are hard to contact at the moment so I am looking for a way to understand what they installed to maybe figuring out why they installed the ppa and if I can remove them.